# Why can't I size this image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I want to be able to resize and center my logo image (which is currently taking up the whole page on preview) but I've tried so many different ways of resizing including adding display: block to the CSS and nothing at all happens. What am I missing??

Besides the standard beginning of HTML file this is all I have in my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="logo">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Stuff logo">
</div>

<div class="button">
<button type="button">Home</button>
<button type=button>Contact</button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the only things I have in my css file:

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
max-width: 200px;
max-height: 200px;
}

.button {
border: 3px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sir here is final answer
sir you had given the class logo to the not to the img
so you have add class to the img not to the

if css you have just do this

```
<div class="logo">
<img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-under-mist-morning-amazing-260nw-1725825019.jpg" alt="Plants and Things logo">
```

here is css

```
.logo img {
max-width:20px;
}
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

There are few region behind it
for example

1. you didn't link the css file with html file.
2. size of your logo may be smaller then max-size

but as solution i would  suggest you to use the css in the img for the temporary solution

like this
try to change with this

```
<img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Plants and Things logo" style="max-width: 20px;max-height:20px">
```

also by using the

```
body{
background-color:red; 
}
```

you can check that your css file is linked or not
also check the console errors

Comment: I've double checked the html and css files are linked. But it certainly appears that no code in CSS is showing up. How do I check console errors?

Comment: Sorry change that, I can have other classes work in CSS fine. It's just the image class that wont work

Comment: for console errors just right click on inspect and then on console

Comment: try this in css img.logo{ width-20px ; height:20px; } also add your whole html and css code in the question so i can see it better.

Comment: Changed it to 20px for height and width - no change.
Updated code to include everything above